# Django how to add members to groups through signals?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

my others signals working such as updating and creating instance but I am not understanding why it's not adding members to group?

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def update_user_profile_from_User_model(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if instance.email:
        MyAuthors.objects.filter(user=instance).update(user=instance,first_name=instance.first_name,last_name=instance.last_name,email=instance.email,is_blog_author=instance.is_blog_author)
        
        if instance.is_blog_author == True:
            my_group = Group.objects.get(name='myauthors')
            print("group name: ", my_group )
            add_user = my_group.user_set.add(instance)  
            print("add_user: ", add_user )
```

print result:

```
group name:  myauthors
add_user:  None
```

I also tried this but didn't work.

```
group = Group.objects.get(name='myauthors')
        if instance.is_blog_author:
           instance.groups.add(group)
           instance.save()
```

**#update1**
my user model:

```
class UserManagement(AbstractUser):
      is_blog_author = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_editor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_subscriber = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**#update2**
After added following changes my user added to group but not saving.

```
if instance.is_blog_author == True:
            User_id = get_user_model()
            user_add_to_group = User_id.objects.get(pk=instance.id)
            my_group = Group.objects.get(name='myauthors')
            print("group name: ", my_group )
            add_user = my_group.user_set.add(user_add_to_group)  
            print("add_user: ", user_add_to_group )
```

**print result:**

```
group name:  myauthors
add_user:  aws
```

how to save in signals ? I tried  add_user.save() and getting this error

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Comment: You are creating an infinte loop with `instance.save()` since that will trigger the given signal again.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant parts of your user model?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I updated my question. please see my user model

Comment: @boyenc: what if you remove the `instance.save()` call at the bottom?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem nothing happening. My others signals working as usual except adding user to group.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem any idea ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237783/discussion-between-boyenec-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: but are you sure the signal "fires"? If you add some print statements, you can likely find out what code path the signal takes.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem yes signal "fires". Now my user added to group but not saving. see my updated question. How to save in signals ?

Comment: Is your `UserManagement` the user model? If that is the case, then shouldn't `my_group.user_set.add(instance)` work?

Comment: `my_group.user_set.add(instance)` not workings see my original question. after added few changes now user adding in group see my updated 2 section. Now problem is I need to be save which I can't

Comment: exactly what error do you get in that case?

Comment: Now I am not getting any error but if I tried to save `add_user.save()` then getting this error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: ah, but you should remove the `add_user = ` part from the `my_group.user_set.add(instance)` method call.

Comment: I removed and now using `add_user = my_group.user_set.add(user_add_to_group)` you might be misunderstood. See my updated2 section.

Comment: @boyenc: but normally the `user_add_to_group` should be identical to the `instance`, since you fetch a user model object with the same primary key.

Comment: I am not understanding why `my_group.user_set.add(instance)`  not working and now `add_user = my_group.user_set.add(user_add_to_group)`  added user in group which I can see from terminal print result but when I go to admin panel I see there is  no user added in group.